# Explicación código - python

Tags: python, django

disculpen, debo de realizar una tabla pero estoy tomando un ejemplo de un archivo similar a lo que debo de hacer, pero en esta operación no le entiendo al código, si alguien me lo puede explicar se lo dejo a continuación.

```
elif request.POST.get('operationNo') == '1':
                    warehouseId = request.POST.get('warehouseId')
                    productId = request.POST.get('productId')
                    startDate = request.POST.get('startDate')
                    endDate = request.POST.get('endDate')
                    prodId = ''
                    prodName = ''
                    warehouse = ''

                    if len(warehouse)==0:
                        warehouse = sWarehouse.objects.all().values()  
                    if((int(warehouseId) >= 1) and (int(productId) == 0)):
                            warehouse = sWarehouse.objects.filter(Q(WarehouseLocationID=warehouseId)).values()
                    if((int(warehouseId) >= 1) and (int(productId) >= 1)):
                            warehouse = sWarehouse.objects.filter(Q(WarehouseLocationID_id=warehouseId)&Q(ProductID_id=productId)).values()
                            if len(warehouse)==0:
                                warehouse = sWarehouse.objects.filter(Q(WarehouseLocationID_id=warehouseId)&Q(WarehouseItemID_id=productId)).values()
                    cntxWarehouse = list (warehouse.values())
                    if cntxWarehouse:
                        for x in range(0, len(cntxWarehouse)):
                            if((cntxWarehouse[x]['WarehouseItemID_id'] != None) and (cntxWarehouse[x]['ProductID_id'] == None)):
                                warehouseItem = sWarehouseItem.objects.get(id=cntxWarehouse[x]['WarehouseItemID_id'])
                                warehouseLocation = sWarehouseLocation.objects.get(id=cntxWarehouse[x]['WarehouseLocationID_id'])
                                product = sWarehouseItem.objects.get(id=cntxWarehouse[x]['WarehouseItemID_id'])
                                cntxWarehouse[x].update({'ExpirationDateTime': warehouseItem.ExpirationDateTime})
                                cntxWarehouse[x].update({'WarehouseLocation': warehouseLocation.Name})
                                cntxWarehouse[x].update({'NameProduct': product.Name})
                                cntxWarehouse[x].update({'Max': warehouseItem.MaximumStock})
                                cntxWarehouse[x].update({'Min': warehouseItem.MinimumStock})

                            elif((cntxWarehouse[x]['ProductID_id'] != None) and (cntxWarehouse[x]['WarehouseItemID_id'] == None)):
                                warehouseProcessIn = sWarehouseMovementProcessIn.objects.filter(ProductID=cntxWarehouse[x]['ProductID_id']).values('ExpirationDateTime').last()
                                warehouseLocation = sWarehouseLocation.objects.get(id=cntxWarehouse[x]['WarehouseLocationID_id'])
                                product = sProduct.objects.get(id=cntxWarehouse[x]['ProductID_id'])
                                if warehouseProcessIn:
                                    expDateTime = warehouseProcessIn['ExpirationDateTime']

                                else:
                                    expDateTime = str('Sin registro')

                                cntxWarehouse[x].update({'ExpirationDateTime': expDateTime})
                                cntxWarehouse[x].update({'WarehouseLocation': warehouseLocation.Name})
                                cntxWarehouse[x].update({'NameProduct': product.Name})
                                cntxWarehouse[x].update({'Max': 0})
                                cntxWarehouse[x].update({'Min': 0})
```

Solo entendí hasta el primer **cntxWarehouse = list (warehouse.values())** de ahí en a delate, no entiendo que trata de hacer.

Comment: hola Her cuando te refieres a hacer una tabla  te refieres a una tabla html(table) con datos quiza de tu Base de Datos ?..o a que te refieres

Comment: Si así es, lo que pasa es que tengo un grafico, y mediante esa grafica me debe de arrojar los datos que lleva (son 2 valores (Meta y Actual)), de estos dos valores (que apareceran en mi tabla como columna base) hay otros 3 campos (Diferencia, Cumulo y Causas), lo cual debo de hacer que meta y actual se sumen o resten (ya sea el caso) y pasarlo a **diferencia** y de diferencia a Cumulo, y en la fila que sigue lo mismo pero ahora cumulo se incremente con la fila de arriba y así sucesivamente, y vi este ejemplo pero no le entiendo. @DiegoAvila

Answer (score 1):

```
                 # cntxWarehouse es una lista no Nula, tiene datos
                 if cntxWarehouse:

                    # recorre todos los elementos de la lista
                    for x in range(0, len(cntxWarehouse)):
                        # este item de posicion X tiene 
                        # WarehouseItemID_id No Nulo y ProductID_id no existe
                        if((cntxWarehouse[x]['WarehouseItemID_id'] != None) and (cntxWarehouse[x]['ProductID_id'] == None)):
                            # crea variables u objetos a partir de este dato encontrado
                            warehouseItem = sWarehouseItem.objects.get(id=cntxWarehouse[x]['WarehouseItemID_id'])
                            warehouseLocation = sWarehouseLocation.objects.get(id=cntxWarehouse[x]['WarehouseLocationID_id'])
                            product = sWarehouseItem.objects.get(id=cntxWarehouse[x]['WarehouseItemID_id'])

                            # en este item x en particular 
                            # actualiza datos haciendo uso de dicionario
                            # llave - valor
                            cntxWarehouse[x].update({'ExpirationDateTime': warehouseItem.ExpirationDateTime})
                            cntxWarehouse[x].update({'WarehouseLocation': warehouseLocation.Name})
                            cntxWarehouse[x].update({'NameProduct': product.Name})
                            cntxWarehouse[x].update({'Max': warehouseItem.MaximumStock})
                            cntxWarehouse[x].update({'Min': warehouseItem.MinimumStock})

                        # en este caso 
                        # el Product_id si existe y el WarehouseItemId no existe
                        elif((cntxWarehouse[x]['ProductID_id'] != None) and (cntxWarehouse[x]['WarehouseItemID_id'] == None)):
                            # crea variables u objetos con la informacion de este item
                            # sacandoles de sWarehouseMovementProcessIn
                            warehouseProcessIn = sWarehouseMovementProcessIn.objects.filter(ProductID=cntxWarehouse[x]['ProductID_id']).values('ExpirationDateTime').last()
                            warehouseLocation = sWarehouseLocation.objects.get(id=cntxWarehouse[x]['WarehouseLocationID_id'])
                            product = sProduct.objects.get(id=cntxWarehouse[x]['ProductID_id'])

                            # warehouseProcessIn resulto no ser Nulo, ni cero, o vacio
                            if warehouseProcessIn:
                                expDateTime = warehouseProcessIn['ExpirationDateTime']

                            else:
                                # no tiene fecha, entonces escribe una nota
                                expDateTime = str('Sin registro')

                            # en este item x en particular 
                            # actualiza datos haciendo uso de dicionario
                            # llave - valor
                            # pero en este caso escribe ceros
                            cntxWarehouse[x].update({'ExpirationDateTime': expDateTime})
                            cntxWarehouse[x].update({'WarehouseLocation': warehouseLocation.Name})
                            cntxWarehouse[x].update({'NameProduct': product.Name})
                            cntxWarehouse[x].update({'Max': 0})
                            cntxWarehouse[x].update({'Min': 0})
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! otra ultima pregunta, yo solo estoy utilizando un select (en el ejemplo utiliza 2)

**    warehouseId = request.POST.get('warehouseId')
                    productId = request.POST.get('productId')**

Yo solo ocupo 1, entonces ¿yo no utilizaría las primeras comparaciones, no? y lo que pasa es que aquí lo dividió en 2 operaciones y yo todo lo estoy haciendo en una sola y eso me confunde mucho, ya que trato de hacerlo igual pero no puedo, porque yo todo lo tengo junto.

Comment: para nuevas preguntas, se formula nuevas preguntas... Hacer preguntas dentro de las respuestas genera desorden, ¿nos ayudas a mantener el sitio ordenado?

Comment: @fredyfx, esta bien, disculpa.

Comment: Descuida, ambos son usuarios nuevos, están aprendiendo :)